Difficulty fixing the code for DDPM with unet using Pyorch
I am studying Deep learning and have an assignment for training a DDPM with UNet on the MNIST handwritten digits dataset. Three ipynb files (model, unet and train_mnist) and one pdf for unet diagram are saved in my github. I filled in the missing parts at #Your Code Here# in "model.ipynb" & "unet.ipynb"
When I run the "unet.ipynb", a warning prompts as below.
NotImplementedError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-21-36a7bf177d9a> in <cell line: 60>()
     62     t=torch.randint(0,1000,(3,))
     63     model=Unet(1000,128)
---> 64     y=model(x,t)
     65     print(y.shape)

5 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py in _forward_unimplemented(self, *input)
    350         registered hooks while the latter silently ignores them.
    351     """
--> 352     raise NotImplementedError(f'Module [{type(self).__name__}] is missing the required "forward" function')
    353 
    354 

NotImplementedError: Module [ModuleList] is missing the required "forward" function

Here is the unet architecture:
class Unet(nn.Module):

    def __init__(self,timesteps,time_embedding_dim,in_channels=3,out_channels=2,base_dim=32,dim_mults=[2,4,8,16]):
        super().__init__()
        assert isinstance(dim_mults,(list,tuple))
        assert base_dim%2==0

        channels=self._cal_channels(base_dim,dim_mults)

        self.init_conv=ConvBnSiLu(in_channels,base_dim,3,1,1)
        self.time_embedding=nn.Embedding(timesteps,time_embedding_dim)

        self.encoder_blocks=nn.ModuleList([EncoderBlock(c[0],c[1],time_embedding_dim) for c in channels])
        self.decoder_blocks=nn.ModuleList([DecoderBlock(c[1],c[0],time_embedding_dim) for c in channels[::-1]])

        self.mid_block=nn.Sequential(*[ResidualBottleneck(channels[-1][1],channels[-1][1]) for i in range(2)],
                                        ResidualBottleneck(channels[-1][1],channels[-1][1]//2))

        self.final_conv=nn.Conv2d(in_channels=channels[0][0]//2,out_channels=out_channels,kernel_size=1)

    def forward(self,x,t=None):
        '''
            Implement the data flow of the UNet architecture
        '''
        # ---------- **** ---------- #
        # YOUR CODE HERE
        t = self.time_embedding

        #initial conv
        x1 = self.init_conv(x)
        #Down
        x2 = self.encoder_blocks(x1,t)
        x3 = self.encoder_blocks(x2[0],t)
        x4 = self.encoder_blocks(x3[0],t)
        x5 = self.encoder_blocks(x4[0],t)
        #Middle
        x6 = self.mid_block(x5[0])
        #Up
        x = self.decoder_blocks(x6,x5[1],t)
        x = self.decoder_blocks(x,x4[1],t)
        x = self.decoder_blocks(x,x3[1],t)
        x = self.decoder_blocks(x,x2[1],t)
        x = self.decoder_blocks(x,x1[1],t)
        #final
        x = self.final_conv(x)

        # ---------- **** ---------- #
        return x


    def _cal_channels(self,base_dim,dim_mults):
        dims=[base_dim*x for x in dim_mults]
        dims.insert(0,base_dim)
        channels=[]
        for i in range(len(dims)-1):
            channels.append((dims[i],dims[i+1])) # in_channel, out_channel

        return channels

if __name__=="__main__":
    x=torch.randn(3,3,224,224)
    t=torch.randint(0,1000,(3,))
    model=Unet(1000,128)
    y=model(x,t)
    print(y.shape)

I have tried to use poe and perplexity and the things are getting worse with bugs. I have also reviewed the documentation in Pytorch and got not idea how to fix the code.
Would someone can spot the problems and explain how to implement the unet? Happy to discuss. Thanks.

Your encoder_blocks and decoder_blocks are ModuleList which are not like nn.Sequential, they are just a collection of modules with no forward function. You need to manually iterate over the modules in your list:
x1 = self.init_conv(x)
for module in self.encoder_blocks:
    x1,_ = module(x1,t)
# Same for decoder ...

The documentation for nn.ModuleList shows a similar example : https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.ModuleList.html
